# How do I float two divs side-by-side without specifying a width?

Tags: css

I have two divs, the first doesn't have much content and the second has a lot of content. I want them to float side-by-side such that the first div is only as wide as the text and the second div fills the remaining amount of horizontal space. And, I don't want to specify fixed widths.

Here is the desired appearance using tables:
http://jsfiddle.net/enRkR/

Can this easily be done with CSS floats, or is a table layout the only way to achieve this look?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with css & it's work in all browsers. Do like this:

```
.right{
    overflow:hidden;
    background:red;
}
.left{
    float:left;
    background:green;
}
```

Check this live example http://jsfiddle.net/enRkR/8/

Comment: Wow, mind-boggling. Who would've thought `overflow:hidden;` is the answer. If I can 1000-up this answer I would ;) Thanks!

Comment: Also if you wish to add space, be sure to use padding and not margin.

Comment: @pixelfreak you could, technically, create 999 different accounts and vote this answer up as promised.

Comment: Any idea why this works? Whats the theory behind this solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="float:left">less content</div>
<div>More content More content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<div>
  <div id="div1" style="float:left">
     content
  </div>
  <div id="div2" >
     content
  </div>
<div>
```

Or

refer this : [How to style Div elements as Tables](http://linuxandfriends.com/2009/04/04/how-to-style-div-elements-as-tables/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<head><title>table using divs</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .div-table{display:table; border:1px solid #003399;}
    .div-table-caption{display:table-caption; background:#009999;}
    .div-table-row{display:table-row;}
    .div-table-col{display:table-cell; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #003399;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="div-table">
    <div class="div-table-caption">This is a caption</div>
    <div class="div-table-row">
    <div class="div-table-col">1st Column</div>
    <div class="div-table-col">2nd Column</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note :** To use these CSS property values, you need to have a web browser which supports them. Unfortunately, that translates to a limited number of web browsers such as IE 8, Firefox 3, Opera 9 and so on