# margin 0 auto simply not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center the middle paragraph in an HTML footer with no success. I used a layout of floats: the first paragraph float to the left, the third paragraph float to the right and the second (middle) paragraph gets margin 0 auto. I also specified the width of each paragraph to 250px. Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

```css
footer {
background: #fff;
border-top: 1px solid #ece9e9;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ece9e9;
clear: both;
overflow: hidden;
}
footer .footer-content {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 40px 0 20px 0;
width: 960px;
background-color: red;
}
footer .footer-content > div {
width: 250px;
display: inline-block;
}
footer h5 {
font-size: 15px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
footer p {
margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.footer-content .footerServices {
background-color: yellow;
float: left;
}
.footer-content .footerNewsLetter {
background-color: yellow;
float: right;
}
.footer-content .footerContact {
background-color: blue;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="footer-content">
    <div class="footerServices">
      <h5>Services</h5>
      <p>
        first paragraph
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="footerContact">
      <h5>Contact Us</h5>
      <p>
        second paragraph
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="footerNewsLetter">
      <h5>Sign To Newsletter</h5>
      <p>
        third paragraph
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `text-align:center` to the .footer-content div:

```
footer .footer-content {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 40px 0 20px 0;
width: 960px;
background-color: red;
text-align:center;
}
```

```css
footer {
background: #fff;
border-top: 1px solid #ece9e9;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ece9e9;
clear: both;
overflow: hidden;
}
footer .footer-content {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 40px 0 20px 0;
width: 960px;
background-color: red;
text-align:center;
}
footer .footer-content > div {
width: 250px;
display: inline-block;
}
footer h5 {
font-size: 15px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
footer p {
margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.footer-content .footerServices {
background-color: yellow;
float: left;
}
.footer-content .footerNewsLetter {
background-color: yellow;
float: right;
}
.footer-content .footerContact {
background-color: blue;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.footer-content .footerServices,.footer-content .footerNewsLetter,.footer-content .footerContact{
 text-align:left; 
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="footer-content">
    <div class="footerServices">
      <h5>Services</h5>
      <p>
        first paragraph
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="footerContact">
      <h5>Contact Us</h5>
      <p>
        second paragraph
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="footerNewsLetter">
      <h5>Sign To Newsletter</h5>
      <p>
        third paragraph
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for `margin: auto` to work, you need to set your middle paragraph to `display:block`

Comment: Thanks, it works but than the last paragraph is not align to the top of the other paragraph as before. Its appear underneath.

Comment: That is because of the float right, you might consider moving the right paragraph before the middle one in your html to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You have some conceptual errors, first of all, you set `display:inline-block` for all `.footer-content > div` and then apply `float` to first and third.

Please, look at [this mine question and relative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118115/pocketgrid-grid-layout-with-fixed-width-navigation-column) that define a scenario very similar to yours. 2 opposite columns left and right, and a central one that adapt its width to remaining space.

Answer (score 0):

As @j08691 said add text-align:center; also add float:none;

```
footer .footer-content {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 40px 0 20px 0;
width: 960px;
background-color: red;text-align:center; float:none;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you try floating all divs to the left?This way they are going to stack up horizontally next to each other.

Then, you can play around with margins to center the one you want in the middle.