# How do I float two divs side-by-side without specifying a width while keeping the right div minimal?

Tags: html, css

I'm referring to the solution of: [How do I float two divs side-by-side without specifying a width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089590/how-do-i-float-two-divs-side-by-side-without-specifying-a-width)

I want the opposite constellation, though: the right `div` should stay at the right side while taking up minimal space (only as much as its contents) and the left `div` should expand to the remaining space.

I tried the following:

```css
.right {
  float: right;
  background: red;
}
.left {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">left div</div>
<div class="right">right div</div>
```

Yet this puts the right `div` on a newline while the left `div` expands to the entire width above.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/enRkR/973/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This is because:**

> A float is a box that is shifted to the left or right on the current line.

*Taken from http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats*

Because the right floated `div` is on a new line it will appear under the left `div`. By placing it before the left `div` they will be on the same line.

**In your original example the `div`s would be stacked like this:**
[image]

**When the right `div` is floated to the right it gets shifted to the right of the current line:**
[image]

**Reversing the order leads to the `div`s being stacked like this:**
[image]

**When the right `div` is floated to the right it gets shifted to the right of the current line:**
[image]

***But:***

> Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not exist.

**So the left `div` effectively moves up to the same line as the right `div`:**
[image]

So, the simplest way to get your desired result would be to change the order of your `div`s in HTML by placing `.right` before `.left`:

```css
.right {
  float: right;
  background: red;
}
.left {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">right div</div>
<div class="left">left div</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain why the left div in this constellation isn't placed on a new line as well? (or why the right div was placed on a new line in the first place in the code I tried)

Comment: @user511287 That would be due to: _Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not exist._ In short, because the right `div` is no longer part of the flow the left `div` is now on the line the right `div` occupies. If I get the chance later I'll try and edit in some more info into my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Precise and thorough answers.

Comment: @user511287 No problem, I've added the extra detail to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there, you just need to change the order of the two divs

instead of

```
<div class="left">left div</div>
<div class="right">right div</div>
```

you put them in the other order. This makes the floating div take up its required space, and the next div (.left) will take up the rest.

```
<div class="right">right div</div>
<div class="left">left div</div>
```

Comment: Weird but works great! I marked Hidden Hobbes' answer as correct because it also explains the reason. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
.right{    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/enRkR/974/

Comment: Thanks this is also a good solution, but relies on the position values of the wrapper, that's why I marked the pure floating solution as correct.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you are trying to achieve?

https://jsfiddle.net/ksg8fnL9/

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="left">left div</div>
    <div class="right">right div</div>
</div>

#wrapper {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
#wrapper > div {
    display:table-cell;
}
#wrapper > div.right{    
    background:red;
}
#wrapper > div.left{
    background:green;
    width:70%
}
```

Comment: "Without specifying a width" is a not that strong of a constraint after all?

Comment: Thanks but no, I want to avoid specifying width entirely as the question states.